# Parse text file using regex to get strings from multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a file `dumpsys.txt` contains:

```
...
...
Receiver Resolver Table:
  Full MIME Types:
      application/vnd.wap.mms-message:
        53929df com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushReceiver
        592f62c com.android.messaging/.receiver.AbortMmsWapPushReceiver
        89c68f5 com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushDeliverReceiver

  Base MIME Types:
      application:
        53929df com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushReceiver
        592f62c com.android.messaging/.receiver.AbortMmsWapPushReceiver
        89c68f5 com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushDeliverReceiver

  Schemes:
      content:
        511868a com.android.messaging/.receiver.SendStatusReceiver (3 filters)

  Non-Data Actions:
      android.intent.action.ACTION_DEFAULT_SMS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED:
        83084fb com.android.messaging/.receiver.DefaultSmsSubscriptionChangeReceiver
      com.android.Bugle.intent.action.ACTION_NOTIFY_CONVERSATIONS_CHANGED:
        a4f4918 com.android.messaging/.widget.BugleWidgetProvider
      com.android.Bugle.intent.action.ACTION_NOTIFY_MESSAGES_CHANGED:
        c979f71 com.android.messaging/.widget.WidgetConversationProvider
      android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW:
        1898156 com.android.messaging/.receiver.StorageStatusReceiver
...
...
```

As seen, there a section called `Receiver Resolver Table` contains some subsections as `Non-Data Actions`. Other sections may contain a subsection called `Non-Data Actions` as well.

I want to extract substrings inside `Non-Data Actions` of `Receiver Resolver Table` preferably using regex in php. 
In my case I want the substring after `/.` in each line under `Non-Data Actions`.

Output example:

```
receiver.DefaultSmsSubscriptionChangeReceiver
widget.BugleWidgetProvider
widget.WidgetConversationProvider
receiver.StorageStatusReceiver
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a free software writing site. And why specify how it should be written if you haven't tried anything yourself? PS: It's useful if you specify the maximum size of the `dumpsys.txt` file.

Comment: I tried many regex, after start reading more about it. but i couldn't end up with useful thing.

Comment: Add your attempts on your question so we can se your effort.

Comment: Well, show us your best version, or the one you like the best. Perhaps regex's aren't the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd divide this into 2 steps, i.e.:

1 - Match the  `Non-Data Actions:` with:

```
/Receiver Resolver Table:.*?Non-Data Actions:(.*?)^[\r\n]/sm
```

2 - Match the `widget`/`receivers` with:

```
%/\.(.*?)$%sm
```

---

```
$text = <<< EOF
Receiver Resolver Table:
  Full MIME Types:
      application/vnd.wap.mms-message:
        53929df com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushReceiver
        592f62c com.android.messaging/.receiver.AbortMmsWapPushReceiver
        89c68f5 com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushDeliverReceiver

  Base MIME Types:
      application:
        53929df com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushReceiver
        592f62c com.android.messaging/.receiver.AbortMmsWapPushReceiver
        89c68f5 com.android.messaging/.receiver.MmsWapPushDeliverReceiver

  Schemes:
      content:
        511868a com.android.messaging/.receiver.SendStatusReceiver (3 filters)

  Non-Data Actions:
      android.intent.action.ACTION_DEFAULT_SMS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED:
        83084fb com.android.messaging/.receiver.DefaultSmsSubscriptionChangeReceiver
      com.android.Bugle.intent.action.ACTION_NOTIFY_CONVERSATIONS_CHANGED:
        a4f4918 com.android.messaging/.widget.BugleWidgetProvider
      com.android.Bugle.intent.action.ACTION_NOTIFY_MESSAGES_CHANGED:
        c979f71 com.android.messaging/.widget.WidgetConversationProvider
      android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW:
        1898156 com.android.messaging/.receiver.StorageStatusReceiver

  something:
      content:
        511868a com.android.messaging/.receiver.SendStatusReceiver (3 filters)
EOF;

preg_match_all('/Receiver Resolver Table:.*?Non-Data Actions:(.*?)^[\r\n]/sm', $text, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$m = $m[1][0];

preg_match_all('%/\.(.*?)$%sm', $m, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$m = $m[1];

print_r($m);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => receiver.DefaultSmsSubscriptionChangeReceiver
    [1] => widget.BugleWidgetProvider
    [2] => widget.WidgetConversationProvider
    [3] => receiver.StorageStatusReceiver
)
```

---

[PHP Demo](https://eval.in/802247)

---

Regex Explanation:

1 - `Receiver Resolver Table:.*?Non-Data Actions:(.*?)^[\r\n]`

```
Match the character string “Receiver Resolver Table:” literally (case insensitive) «Receiver Resolver Table:»
Match any single character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “Non-Data Actions:” literally (case insensitive) «Non-Data Actions:»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) «^»
Match a single character present in the list below «[\r\n]»
   The carriage return character «\r»
   The line feed character «\n»
```

2 - `/\.(.*?)$`

```
Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) «$»
```

Comment: Thanks @Pedro Lobito. Can you add some explanations for your regex. I am beginner on this, if possible I will be thankful.

Comment: You're welcome @Aan. I've posted a regex explanation.